# using .Items and .Add not being recognised

Tags: vb.net

i need help in my code:

```
Private Sub AddButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
         ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddButton.Click
    If Ingredients.Text <> "" And QuantityBox.Text <> "" And UnitBox.Text <> "" Then
        Ingredients.Items.Add(ListBox1.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

On my third line, there is a problem. when i try to debug it tells me that "Items is not a member of System.Windows.Form.Textbox. this also happens with Add too. Is there a problem with my code, because i have done this code at school and this problem is not happening there.

Comment: If `Ingredients` is a `TextBox` it has no `Items` property.

Comment: I think you are trying to give 2 different objects the same name. You cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code (and a large amount of assumptions), I think you got the listbox and the textbox mixed up. Try this?

```
Private Sub AddButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AddButton.Click
    If Ingredients.Text <> "" And QuantityBox.Text <> "" And UnitBox.Text <> "" Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(Ingredients.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```